# Stripping character at the start or end of a string

Tags: javascript

In python there is a method to replace a certain character(s) at the edges of a string, such as:

```
>>> "   , hello,".strip(", ")
'hello'
```

Is there a method to do this in javascript, or does it need to be done with a regular expression? For example:

```js
console.log("'" + "   , hello,".replace(/^\W+|\W+$/g, "") + "'");
```

Comment: No, a regular expression is the best way to go about it

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no such method. There is only [.trim()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim), which only trims white space.